# Как сделать автоматическую нумерацию строк в GRID?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, ado.net

У меня есть дерево в `XAML` которое я могу редактировать и добавлять столько угодно детей. И есть `Grid` в котором отображено два поля `номер` i `описание поля`
Нужно сделать автоматическую нумерацию в поле грид, но брать первые числа брать с дерева а последнее уже с номер поля, то есть если дерево имеет трех уровненную систему то поле должно бить `1.1.1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую нумерацию?

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку решения данной задачи.

Comment: добавьте описание класса дерева, вместе попробуем его доработать. также будет хорошо посмотреть на кусочек кода, который инициализирует дерево данными.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно не копаться в гриде, а сделать свою модель, которую уже потом привязать к интерфейсу. В самой модели строки должно быть два свойства  -

```
public int Num {get; set;} //для хранения номера строки в узле и 
public string Nr 
{
    get { return Node.Nr + '.' + Num.ToString(); } //Node - узел в котором хранится строка
    private set {}
}
```

В самом узле нужно поступить аналогично